# Why inner join not working with case clause in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this SQL query but this not work, I am very confused why this not work. Does anyone have an example or solution for this?

SQL:

```
select e.state 
       case when  e.state = 'a' then 'cation'  else 'pasive' end 
from miss as e INNER JOIN 
     mr as a
```

ERROR :

> syntax error at or near "case"
>            on e.id = a.id;

```
Solution: select e.state , 
       case when  e.state = 'a' then 'cation'  else 'pasive' end 
from miss as e INNER JOIN 
     mr as a
```

Comment: How do You know it does not work? Does it result in error message? Or does it return different result than You expect?

Comment: You have not split your column separated by `,`. So, you just include `,` before case expression & will work.

Comment: This is error: ERROR:  `syntax error at or near "case"`

Comment: As @YogeshSharma suggested, You are missing `,` between `e.state` and `case`.

Comment: You are missing a join condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  e.state,    -- you were missing a , here
  case when e.state = 'a' then 'cation'  else 'pasive' end 
from
  miss as e
INNER JOIN 
  mr as a
    -- You're missing the join predicate here : ON e.something = a.something
```

Without some example data, or any description of what you're trying to achieve, it is possible that you don't have a join predicate because you really meant to use `UNION`?

```
SELECT
  e.state,
  case when e.state = 'a' then 'cation'  else 'pasive' end 
FROM
(
   SELECT * FROM miss
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM mr
)
  e
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.